# Angular 2 class component methods vs functions

Tags: angular, function, class, components

I'm learning Angular 2 and am confused in typescript by function vs. class component body methods.

For example:

I have a function that creates a custom validation rule for an input element in a form that is validated in a component called CustomerComponent. When I move this function into the component class body as a method, it doesn't work, but when I create a separate function just below the import statements above the component class body, it does work. See below:

```
function ratingRange(c: AbstractControl): {[key:string]: boolean} | null {
```

...}

```
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {....
}
```

So I have to keep this as a separate function. My question is why do we need typescript functions in component classes when we already have method bodies in the component class body itself? I thought that methods in the component class body perform some kind of logic in the template and so functions are superfluous.

Comment: If the function doesn't need any instance state, why *would* you put it in the class?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Testability, for instance. You can easily spy or mock class method but will have hard time doing this for standalone imported functions.

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough information. *When I move this function into the component class body as a method, it doesn't work* - where is the code for this and what 'doesn't work' mean? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is required here.

Comment: @estus you can export the function too, if you want to test it separately. And it's generally wise to avoid mocking parts of the class under test, that would be testing implementation rather than behaviour, then it doesn't matter if the public method you're testing is calling functions or other methods.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is about testing methodology rather than anything else, but using it as a function makes testing the implementation impossible. Class methods can be considered  separate units depending on the situation, and the thing you're suggesting is basically integration/functional test, not unit test.

Comment: Post the part of your code where you call ratingRange().